# Filter a pandas dataframe if two rows cross matches columnwise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
key     a0  p0   a1 p1  a2  p2  d1  d2  prot

2136933 GLN 35  GLN 176 GLN 39  4   137 2CPK
2136934 GLN 35  GLN 176 GLN 39  4   137 3TNQ
2136933 GLN 35  GLN 176 GLN 39  4   137 5O5M
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 1ATP
2136962 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 181 138 4   1ATP
2136960 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 1L3R
2136962 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 181 138 4   1L3R
2136910 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 35  4   138 2CPK
2136993 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 181 138 4   2CPK
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 3TNQ
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 4XW5
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 5O5M
2136849 GLN 39  GLN 181 GLN 35  4   142 1ATP
```

I want to retain rows only where d1=d2 and d2=d1 for a pair of rows and the keys should be within +/-10 range of each other. The expected result should be following:

```
key     a0  p0   a1 p1  a2  p2  d1  d2  prot

2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 1ATP
2136962 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 181 138 4   1ATP
2136960 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 1L3R
2136962 GLN 39  GLN 177 GLN 181 138 4   1L3R
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 3TNQ
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 4XW5
2136961 GLN 35  GLN 177 GLN 39  4   138 5O5M
```

Comment: You could just go over each pair of rows and check whether they "cross-match" or not.

Answer (score 1):

Merge with itself using one pair comparing then check other conditions

```
t = df.merge(df, how='inner',left_on='d1', right_on='d2', suffixes=['','_y'])
t[(t['d2']==t['d1_y']) & (t['key']-t['key_y']).abs().lt(10)] \
   .drop(columns=t.columns[t.columns.str.endswith('_y')]).drop_duplicates()

        key   a0  p0   a1   p1   a2   p2   d1   d2  prot
9   2136961  GLN  35  GLN  177  GLN   39    4  138  1ATP
12  2136960  GLN  35  GLN  177  GLN   39    4  138  1L3R
18  2136961  GLN  35  GLN  177  GLN   39    4  138  3TNQ
21  2136961  GLN  35  GLN  177  GLN   39    4  138  4XW5
24  2136961  GLN  35  GLN  177  GLN   39    4  138  5O5M
30  2136962  GLN  39  GLN  177  GLN  181  138    4  1ATP
36  2136962  GLN  39  GLN  177  GLN  181  138    4  1L3R
```